# How to concat Pandas dataframe columns

Tags: python, pandas

How to concat columns of different data types in a Pandas dataframe such that if column `number` is concatenated with column `operator`, and I do a `groupby('user').sum()`, I can have the appropriate aggregation:

```
    number   operator user
id                      
1      193        -    A
2      332        +    B
3     4434        +    A
4      432        -    C
5      652        +    C
6      567        +    D


#after concat:

    number operator user
id                      
1     -193        -    A
2      332        +    B
3     4434        +    A
4     -432        -    C
5      652        +    C
6      567        +    D


#df.groupby('user').sum()

      number
user        
A       4241
B        332
C        220
D        567
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `loc` with boolean mask to make the 'number' values negative:

```
In [34]:
df.loc[df['operator'] == '-', 'number'] = -df['number']
df

Out[34]:
    number operator user
id                      
1     -193        -    A
2      332        +    B
3     4434        +    A
4     -432        -    C
5      652        +    C
6      567        +    D
```

You can then `groupby` on 'user' can call `sum` on 'number' column:

```
In [35]:    
df.groupby('user')['number'].sum()

Out[35]:
user
A    4241
B     332
C     220
D     567
Name: number, dtype: int64
```